# Error, Publishing the application on linux server

Tags: linux, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to publish the application (blazor WebAssembly with individual authentication and asp.net core hosted) to a linux server, but it gives me an error,
I tried to add a certificate and a few startup options, but it did not help.

**Linux:**

```
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://10.0.2.200:443: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.<Bind>g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Polls.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\.............Polls\Server\Program.cs:line 16
```

**startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddDevExpressBlazor();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("PollsConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<AppDbContext>();

            //services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(
            //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            //services.AddTransient<AppDbContext>();

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCertificate(options =>
                 {
                     options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                 })
                    .AddCertificateCache();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var httpsSection = Configuration.GetSection("HttpServer:Endpoints:Https");

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 443;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();

                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

        }
```

**appsettings.json (certificate):**

```
"Key": {
    "Type": "File",
    "FilePath": "/etc/ssl/private/certificate11.pfx",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Name": "/CN=private.key"
  },
```

**appsettings.Development.json (certificate):**

```
"HttpServer": {
    "Endpoints": {

      "Https": {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 443,
        "Scheme": "https",
        "FilePath": "/etc/ssl/private/certificate11.pfx"
      }
    }
  }
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you edit the question as the error at the start is all stack trace and the actual error message and location is missing

Comment: I edited the linux error and added a program.cs which shows the error, line with CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

Comment: error: `System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://10.0.2.200:443: address already in use.` - your linux box is already listening on port 443 on a different service/web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linux target host is already has a process that is listening on port 443

Use something like `netstat` to see what it might be
https://www.tecmint.com/find-listening-ports-linux/